# calling uglifyjs (javascript function) from within a perl script

Tags: perl, javascript

I have a directory full of .js files and I have already written a perl script that displays the source code from all of the .js files in a new file.  The source files in the new file are all separated by a header that shows the name,date, and size of the source file.

For example:

file1|creation date|size

Contents of file 1

file2|creation date|size

Contents of file 2

I would like to call the function uglifyjs (from within a perl script)to minimize the .js file without changing the creation date.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [SO] as it seems to have nothing to do with Unix and/or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a package uglifyjs in perl but you may use [JavaScript::Minifier](http://search.cpan.org/~pmichaux/JavaScript-Minifier-1.05/lib/JavaScript/Minifier.pm).